# SHA1 form .exe file in C#

Tags: c#, exe, sha1

I hope that someone could help me with reading exe files in C# and create a SHA1 hash from it. I have tried to read from executable file using StreamReader and BinaryReader. Then using  built-in SHA1 algorithm I tried to create a hash but without success. The algorithm results for StreamReader was "AEUj+Ppo5QdHoeboidah3P65N3s=" and for BinaryReader was "rWXzn/CoLLPBWqMCE4qcE3XmUKw=". Can anyone help me to acheive SHA1 hash from exe file? Thx.

BTW Sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Read all bytes with File.ReadAllBytes( path ). Then use the byte[] as input to the SHA1 function.

Comment: @Mikael: I see no reason to read the whole file into memory when it can be hashed in a streaming fashion very easily.

Comment: @Jon, I would do a stream personally, unless data was known to easily fit in memory.

Comment: @Mikael: Exactly - so why call ReadAllBytes? :)

Comment: I was trying to make a quick/easy remark for the user and point in the directions of using bytes/binary data. But the streaming code is just as short and simple, so -1 on me for that. But maybe not that clear to the asker that a stream actually uses bytes. The difference between bytes and a string is what the asker missed. If I had my VS at hand when making the note (always helps to test any answer in VS), I wouldn't have made a note but answered much in the same way you did instead.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a `StreamReader` - that will try to convert the opaque binary data into *text* data... an exe file is *not* text data.

Just use a `FileStream` and call `ComputeHash`:

```
byte[] hash;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(stream);
}
string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Comment: I want to get the hash of any running process, would'nt this be time consuming ? Is there any faster method of calculating the hash in this scenario? 
Thanks alot in advance

Comment: @Hossein: What do you mean by a process? Do you mean the original executable file? How large are the executables you're considering, and what sort of performance is acceptable?

Comment: Thanks, Running Processes in windows machine.Mostly they are system based processes, but there are other processes such as oracle or msSQLServer processes and services as well.
Actually i am trying to make sure only a handful of white-listed processes are running at the moment.Currenly i am pooling every 1 ms in c# to get list of processes and compare them agains a whitelist. WMI is slow and also not that dependable since i can miss some process events.
and about the performance part, i need something fast in this regard if possible.

Comment: @Hossein: Polling every millisecond seems like a bad idea - and you definitely wouldn't be wanting to hash the files of all processes that often. Can't you just hash if you see a file with a new filename or if the size of the file has changed?

Comment: filename can be changed to look like any legitimized processes.The size isnt any better either since any malware can try to look like a legit processes by faking its attributes including its size.Hashing would give me a very good mean for spotting malwares or unwanted apps.

Comment: @Hossein: I'm suggesting that you hash, but cache that hash by name and size. Maybe do a *full* scan once an hour or something like that, but you can't possibly expect to hash the files used by all processes every millisecond. To be honest, I have to wonder why you're reinventing the wheel here at all - what's wrong with all the existing malware detection tools, which hook into system calls etc?

Comment: Actually i am trying to use hooking as well but i have not been successful so far, so instead i am trying to create a temporary solution till i can finish the actual application.
Thanks alot again.i'll see how i can make this alittle more tolerable :)

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader` implements `TextReader` so we are not in a binary world :-)